# Unıque Random Number Check form Array c++

Tags: c++, random

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool cont = false;
    string str;
    int num, num2;
    cin >> str >> num;
    int arr[10];

    int a = pow(10, num);
    int b = pow(10, (num - 1));
    srand(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));

    do {
        num2 = rand() % (a - b) + b;
        int r;
        int i = 0;
        int cpy = num2;

        while (cpy != 0) {
            r = cpy % 10;
            arr[i] = r;
            i++;
            cpy = cpy / 10;
        }

        for (int m = 0; m < num; m++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (m != j) {
                    if (arr[m] == arr[j]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        cont = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << num2 << endl;
    } while (!cont);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to take a number from the user and produce such a random number.

For example, if the user entered 8, an 8-digit random number.This number must be unique, so each number must be different from each other,for example:

user enter 5

random number=11225(invalid so take new number)

random number =12345(valid so output)

To do this, I divided the number into its digits and threw it into the array and checked whether it was unique. The Program takes random numbers from the user and throws them into the array.It's all right until this part.But my function to check if this number is unique using the for loop does not work.

Comment: Is 45678 a valid number for `5` or does the number need to contain the digits `[1, entered_number]`?

Comment: Please be more specific. "but I get an error" is not a good description.

Comment: Rather use [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) from the c++ standard library. IIRC there were already agorithms implemented to generate uniques sets and ranges of random numbers.

Comment: It's valid because each digit is different.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a unique sequence 0-9, a random shuffle, and a counter (bumped if the lead digit is zero, and therefore skipped).

Comment: Warning: `pow` with integers can fail hilariously because `pow` operates on floating point numbers. When you get the result and stuff it back into an `int`, you may find you got 99.999999997 instead of 100 and the integer will be truncated to 99.

Comment: [This kinda thing](https://godbolt.org/z/M74seE) is something like what my last comment referred to. Obviously if you want a hard integer from this a little more work would be done, but it seems a pretty worthwhile thing if you don't have to repeatedly hope for a distinct number from `rand()`. Rather, start with what you know you allow, shuffle it, and go form there.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need your digits to be unique, it's easier to guarantee the uniqueness up front and then mix it around. The problem-solving principle at play here is to start where you are the most constrained. For you, it's repeating digits, so we ensure that will never happen. It's a lot easier than verifying if we did or not.

This code example will print the unique number to the screen. If you need to actually store it in an `int`, then there's extra work to be done.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> digits(10);
  std::iota(digits.begin(), digits.end(), 0);
  std::shuffle(digits.begin(), digits.end(), std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

  int x;
  std::cout << "Number: ";
  std::cin >> x;

  for (auto it = digits.begin(); it != digits.begin() + x; ++it) {
    std::cout << *it;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

A few sample runs:

```
Number: 7
6253079

Number: 3
893

Number: 6
170352
```

The vector `digits` holds the digits 0-9, each only appearing once. I then shuffle them around. And based on the number that's input by the user, I then print the first `x` single digits.

The one downside to this code is that it's possible for 0 to be the first digit, and that may or may not fit in with your rules. If it doesn't, you'd be restricted to a 9-digit number, and the starting value in `std::iota` would be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

First I'm going to recommend you make better choices in naming your variables. You do this:

```
    bool cont = false;
    string str;
    int num, num2;
    cin >> str >> num;
```

What are num and num2? Give them better names. Why are you cin >> str? I can't even see how you're using it later. But I presume that num is the number of digits you want.

It's also not at all clear what you're using a and b for. Now, I presume this next bit of code is an attempt to create a number. If you're going to blindly try and then when done, see if it's okay, why are you making this so complicated. Instead of this:

```
    num2 = rand() % (a - b) + b;
    int r;
    int i = 0;
    int cpy = num2;

    while (cpy != 0) {
        r = cpy % 10;
        arr[i] = r;
        i++;
        cpy = cpy / 10;
    }
```

You can do this:

```
 for(int index = 0; index < numberOfDesiredDigits; ++index) {
     arr[index] = rand() % 10;
 }
```

I'm not sure why you went for so much more complicated.

I think this is your code where you validate:

```
    // So you iterate the entire array
    for (int m = 0; m < num; m++)
    {
        // And then you check all the values less than the current spot.
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            // This if not needed as j is always less than m.
            if (m != j) {
                // This if-else is flawed
                if (arr[m] == arr[j]) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    cont = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You're trying to make sure you have no duplicates. You're setting `cont == true` if the first and second digit are different, and you're breaking as soon as you find a dup. I think you need to rethink that.

```
bool areAllUnique = true;
for (int m = 1; allAreUnique && m < num; m++) {
    for (int j = 0; allAreUnique && j < m; ++j) {
        allAreUnique = arr[m] != arr[j];
    }
}
```

As soon as we encounter a duplicate, `allAreUnique` becomes false and we break out of both for-loops.

Then you can check it.

Note that I also start the first loop at 1 instead of 0. There's no reason to start the outer loop at 0, because then the inner loop becomes a no-op.

---

A better way is to keep a set of valid digits -- initialized with 1 to 10. Then grab a random number within the size of the set and grabbing the n'th digit from the set and remove it from the set. You'll get a valid result the first time.

Comment: 1 - 10 would repeat the number 1.